# R aggregate by a variable then find out proportion of a each column

Tags: r, bar-chart, plyr

Sorry, I've tried my best but I didn't find the answer. As beginner, I'm not sure that I'm able to put the question clearly. Thanks in advance.

So I have a dataframe with data about consumption with 24000 rows.
In this dataframe, there is a series of variable about the number of objects bought within the last two months  :
NumberOfCoat, NumberOfShirt, NumberOfPants, NumberOfShoes...
And there is a variable "profession" registered by number.

So now the data looks looks like this

```
            profession  NumberOfCoat  NumberOfShirt  NumberOfShoes
individu1       1              1             1             1
individu2       3              2             4             1
individu3       2              2             0             0
individu4       6              0             3             2
individu5       5              0             2             3
individu6       7              1             0             5
individu7       4              3             1             2
```

I would like to know the structure of consumption by profession and get something like this :

```
           ProportionOfCoat  ProportionOfShirt  ProportionOfShoe...
profession1       0.3                0.5                0.1
profession2       0.1                0.2                0.4
profession3       0.2                0.6                0.1
profession4       0.1                0.1                0.2
```

I don't know if it is clear, but finally I want to be able to say :

10% of clothing products that doctors bought are Tshirts whereas 20% of what teachers bought are T-shirts.

And finally, I'd like to draw a stacked barplot where each stack is scaled to sum to 100%.
I suppose that we can you dplyr ?

Thank you very much !!

Comment: `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(profession) %>% summarise_all(sum) %>% mutate_at(vars(-profession), prop.table)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is more than one question. Please ask only one at a time. Also please show what you have tried to get to an answer.

Comment: ...and you don't really even need to aggregate to make a barplot; just use `position = 'fill'`: `library(tidyverse); df %>% gather(df, var, val, -profession) %>% ggplot(aes(profession, val, fill = var)) + geom_col(position = 'fill')`

Answer (score 0):

```
temp <- aggregate( . ~ profession, data=zzz, FUN=sum)
cbind(temp[1],temp[-1]/rowSums(temp[-1]))
```

or also using  prop.table

Answer (score 0):

As other people noted, it is always better to post a reproducible example, I´ll try to post one with my solution, which is longer than the ones already posted but, for the same reason, maybe clearer.

First you should create an example dataframe:

```
set.seed(10) # I set a seed cause I´ll use the sample() function
n <- 1:100 # vector from 1 to 100 to obtain the number of products bought
p <- 1:8 # vector for obtaining id of professions
profession <- sample(p,50, replace = TRUE)
NumberOfCoat <- sample(n,50, replace = TRUE)
NumberOfShirt <- sample(n,50, replace = TRUE)
NumberOfShoes <- sample(n,50, replace = TRUE)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(profession, NumberOfCoat, 
                      NumberOfShirt, NumberOfShoes))
```

Once you got the dataframe, you can explain what you have tried so far, or a possible solution. Here I used `dplyr`.

```
df <- df %>% group_by(profession) %>% summarize(coats = sum(NumberOfCoat),
                                            shirts = sum(NumberOfShirt),
                                            shoes = sum(NumberOfShoes)) %>%
             mutate(tot_prod = coats + shirts + shoes,
                    ProportionOfCoat = coats/tot_prod,
                    ProportionOfShirt = shirts/tot_prod,
                    ProportionofShoes = shoes/tot_prod) %>%
            select(profession, ProportionOfCoat, ProportionOfShirt, 
                   ProportionofShoes)
```

`df`corresponds to the second dataframe you show, where you have the proportion of each product bought by each profession. In my example looks like this:

```
 profession ProportionOfCoat ProportionOfShirt ProportionofShoes
       <int>            <dbl>             <dbl>             <dbl>
1          1        0.3910483         0.2343934         0.3745583
2          2        0.4069641         0.3525571         0.2404788
3          3        0.3330804         0.3968134         0.2701062
4          4        0.2740657         0.3952435         0.3306908
5          5        0.2573991         0.3784753         0.3641256
6          6        0.2293814         0.3543814         0.4162371
7          7        0.2245841         0.3955638         0.3798521
8          8        0.2861635         0.3490566         0.3647799
```

If you want to produce a stacked barplot, you have to reshape your data to a long format in order to be able to use `ggplot2`. As @alistaire noted, you can do it with the `gather` function from the `tidyr` package.

```
df <- df %>% gather(product, proportion, -profession)
```

And finally you can plot it with `ggplot2`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=profession, y=proportion, fill=product)) + 
       geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for you patient response.  It globally worked for my. However, I think it is because of NAs in my data, the sum of proportions of different products by profession is not 100%... and at the end the bars are not of even length... would you please tell me what to do ? thanks again !

Comment: Oh ! I think maybe it's because the population of different professions are not equal.... like my profession 1 has 20 people and profession 2 has 300 people and profession 3 has 84 people...  :'(

Comment: That shouldn´t be a problem, the data I gave has the same characteristic, `df %>% group_by(profession) %>% summarize(np = n())`with that you can check that there are different number of individuals for each profession.